# How to install, load CUDA driver and set Matlab to do GPU processing on my Apple Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.10 Yosemite?

Tags: matlab, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, osx-yosemite

I would like to use some parallel computing function using the GPU. I tried to use gpuarray function but I have got the following error message:

> There is a problem with the CUDA driver or with this GPU device. Be
>   sure that you have a supported GPU and that the latest driver is
>   installed.

Caused by:

```
The CUDA driver could not be loaded.
```

The library name used was

```
'/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib'.
```

The **error** was:

```
dlopen(/usr/local/cuda/lib/libcuda.dylib, 10): image not found
```

Therefore I would like to know how to install, load CUDA driver and set Matlab to do GPU processing on my Apple Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.10 Yosemite ?

My GPU is a NVidia GeForce 750M. My Macbook Pro Retina (15") is from the late 2013 generation.

I'm running Matlab 2014b

Thank you for your help and support,

Best,

Adrien

EDIT: thank you Robert C., I followed these instructions and Matlab with GPU seems to work fine now :)

Comment: I believe there are being big problems with Matlab 2014b and Yosemite. The IT departament of my uni has send a message suggesting quite strongly to NOT have both. To use just the new matlab or just the new version of OS X because they are having huge issues with that.

Comment: Hi, so far Matlab2014b works fine for me but I just can't figure out how to set the cuda driver properly and make Matlab use it. I want to believe this is just a question of setting things up rather than a Yosemite-Matlab issue...

Comment: Follow the instructions in the CUDA [getting started guide for Mac OS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html#abstract).  Note that there are environment variables that need to be set.

Comment: Thank you Robert, it seems to work well now as I followed your advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded following the instructions in the CUDA [getting started guide for Mac OS](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html#abstract) thanks to Robert.